# Is it possible to create an action that can receive different types of parameters? (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, object, parameters, universal

I was woundering if it is possible to make an action that can receive different types of objects. For example if I want to pass UILabels and UIButtons, to the same action, but only one at the time. What I'm not looking for is something like this:

```
- (void)actionInitWithButton:(UIButton *)button Label:(UILabel *)label;
```

More something like this:

```
- (void)actionInitWithObject:(UniversalObject *)object;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, they're simply called `id`. It's a principal concept of the language.

The alternative is `NSObject`, but this is typically used for subclassing -- `id` covers a more broad spectrum as not all (but most) objects inherit from `NSObject`.

Ex.

```
- (void)actionInitWithObject:(id)something
{
    if([something isKindOfClass:[UIButton class])
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)something;
        ...
    } else if ([something isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)something;
        ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)... my next problem is now that I can't find center on an id object.. would you know what to do here

Comment: If you're going to treat the `id` as anything but a generic pointer, you need to cast it. XCode will let you cast an `id` to any object, so you need to protect against runtime exceptions.